# Python Selenium - Cannot find element on page

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've perused SO for quite a while and cannot find the exact or similar solution to my current problem. This is my first post on SO, so I apologize if my formatting is off.

**The Problem -**
I'm trying to find a button on a webpage to punch me into a timeclock automatically. I am able to sign in and navigate to the correct page (it seems the page is dynamically loaded, as switching from different tabs like "Time Management" or "Pay Period" do not change the URL).

**Attempts to solve -**
I've tried using direct and indirect XPaths, CSS Selectors, IDs, Classes, Names, and all have failed. Included below are the different code attempts to find the button, and also a snippet of code including the button.

**Button - HTML**
[Full Page HTML Source Code](https://pastebin.com/QW62Fgj7)

```
<td>
    <a onclick="return OnEmpPunchClick2(this);" id="btnEMPPUNCH_PUNCH" class="timesheet button icon " href="javascript:__doPostBack('btnEMPPUNCH_PUNCH','')">
        <span> Punch</span></a>
    <input type="hidden" name="hdfEMPPUNCH_PUNCH" id="hdfEMPPUNCH_PUNCH" value="0">
</td>
```

**Attempts - PYTHON - ALL FAIL TO FIND**

```
#All these return: "Unable to locate element"
self.browser.find_element_by_id("btnEMPPUNCH_PUNCH")
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='btnEMPPUNCH_PUNCH']")
self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#btnEMPPUNCH_PUNCH')

#I attempted a manual wait:
wait=WebDriverWait(self.browser,30)
button = wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#btnEMPPUNCH_PUNCH')))

#And even manually triggering the script:
self.browser.execute_script("javascript:__doPostBack('btnEMPPUNCH_PUNCH','')")
self.browser.execute_script("__doPostBack('btnEMPPUNCH_PUNCH','')")
#Returns Message: ReferenceError: __doPostBack is not defined
```

None of these work, and I cannot seem to figure out why that is. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What kind of errors do you get while attempting the code?

Comment: Sorry @arundeepchohan - I had added the errors as comments in the code itself. The "find_element_by_xyz" code brackets return "Unable to locate element"

The "wait.until" code bracket oddly returns no Exception error, but it fails.

Lastly, attempting to execute the script itself returns "referenceError: __doPostBack is not defined"

Comment: What website is it from?

Comment: It's from Ultipro, my company uses it for HR purposes, tracking time sheets, pay stubs, 401k etc. You can't make a dummy account because each company's is setup unique. I added the websites source code to a pastebin link above.

Comment: Can you find it from the developer tools? Right click and copy xpath or css selector.

Comment: Yes, I've done both of those. The CSS Selector above is the one I found in the developer tool. The XPath I also used from the dev tools and both failed.

Comment: Try doing a presence on the wait to see if the button is visible or just not interactable.

Comment: Or if there's any iframes.